# What should Roblox Studio plugins use for persistent storage?

Tags: roblox, roblox-studio

For Studio plugins that want to save user preferences, where should that data be saved?

Let's say for example, I have a list of toggle switches, and I want to save what the user has toggled on and off. Where should that go? Is there a place to store data that persists across DataModel sessions? The plugin [documentation](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Plugin) and [tutorials](https://create.roblox.com/docs/studio/building-studio-widgets) don't cover this use case.

[DataStores](https://create.roblox.com/docs/scripting/data/data-stores) don't seem to be the right place as they are on a "per-experience" basis, require explicit permission to work in Studio, and are a security risk to expose for a plugin that doesn't care about a user's game data.

I've never used [LocalStorageService](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/LocalStorageService), but the name implies that it might be the right place, but the docs are currently just a skeleton.

Is there a way to store any data with a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `plugin` object has a function called [SetSetting](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Plugin#SetSetting) that allows you to store information in the plugin itself. According to the docs :

> Stores a given value for later use under the given key. The value will persist even after studio is closed.

You can retrieve this data using the [GetSetting](https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/Plugin#GetSetting) function.

```lua
local plugin = script:FindFirstAncestorOfClass("Plugin")

local key = "foo"
local defaultValue = 0

-- check if anything has been stored already
local existingValue = plugin:GetSetting(key)
if not existingValue then
    -- if not, store the value for later
    plugin:SetSetting(key, defaultValue)
    existingValue = defaultValue
end

print(existingValue)
```